# Meaning of Date Given

Tags: meaning

> **(3) Suspect medical product(s), including vaccines administered on the same date.**
>
> (i) Name;
>
> (ii) Dose, frequency, and route or site of administration used;
>
> (iii) Number of previous vaccine doses;
>
> (iv) Vaccination date(s) and time(s);
>
> (v) Diagnosis for use (indication);
>
> (vi) Whether the product is a combination product (as defined in 3.2(e) of this chapter);
>
> (vii) Whether the adverse experience abated after product use stopped or dose reduced;
>
> (viii) Whether the adverse experience reappeared after reintroduction of the product;
>
> (ix) Lot number;
>
> (x) Expiration date;
>
> (xi) National Drug Code (NDC) number, or other unique identifier; and
>
> (xii) Concomitant medical products and therapy dates.
>
> (4) Vaccine(s) administered in the 4 weeks prior to the vaccination date.
>
> (i) Name of vaccine;
>
> (ii) Manufacturer;
>
> (iii) Lot number;
>
> (iv) Route or site of administration;
>
> ***(v) Date given; and***
>
> (vi) Number of previous doses. [CFR - Code of Federal Regulations Title 21](https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfCFR/CFRSearch.cfm?CFRPart=600&showFR=1&subpartNode=21:7.0.1.1.1.4)

Could you please help me with why they put "given" behind date?

Is there any special reason?

And why is this "date given" instead of "given date"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because they are asking about the date that the drug was **administered**.

Comment: Then does it mean "date (when the drug was) given"?

Comment: @MangoGummy, yes, (the) date (the drug was) given would be a longer version of the phrase